# How to create an EditText with a background with rounded ends

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-edittext

How do I create an EditText like this? I tried many times but the cursor is always outside the round corners.

[image]

Comment: Check the TextInputLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a new drawable file with name "background.xml" inside your project's drawable folder and write these inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#f1f4f9" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#f1f4f9" />
    <corners
        android:radius="24dp" />
</shape>
```

Then in activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:hint="Your full name"
        android:padding="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use left padding in edittext

android:leftpadding="20dp"